# Laravel Nova 3 Register Vuex Store

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I am trying to add Vuex Store for my Custom Tool but I could'nt do that.

How can I register tool.js ? I found different ways but never works on me. If you work with Nova and what is your way ? Please let me know. Thank you.